# Unsuccessful API Call

Tags: api, android-studio, kotlin

I am fairly new at working with API calls in Android Studio and I'm having trouble with a block of code. It's a function that deletes a specific task item from a remote database.

Here's my code.

RepoInterface:

```
    suspend fun deleteRemoteTask(token: String, id: Int, task: Task): Response<Task>
```

RepoImplementation:

```
override suspend fun deleteRemoteTask(token: String, id: Int, task : Task): Response<Task> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return@withContext try {
             apiService.deleteTask(token, id, task)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "deleteRemoteTask: Api Failed to run")
            throw Exception(e.localizedMessage)
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
        val response = remote.deleteRemoteTask(token, id, task)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            local.deleteTask(response.body()!!)
            return local.getTaskByID(response.body()!!.id)
        } else {
            throw Exception("Repo: API Call unsuccessful")
        }
    }
```

I'm confident that my interface and implementation are set up correctly, but the logic in my actual repository is a bit shaky, as I keep getting an Exception thrown. The data is coming down from the View -> Viewmodel -> UseCase -> Repo -> RepoImp -> Interface -> API.

I also have

Comment: `as I keep getting an Exception thrown` What is the desired behavior? Is it that the RepoImplementation should not throw an exception? Or is it that the repository should handle the exception and not throw it back to the caller?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but the `catch` block in `deleteRemoteTask` should either specify the original exception as cause or just rethrow `e` directly. Creating a new exception like this loses the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

We would need a bit more info. The flow is not well implemented but no worries we all start by a point :D, I will adapt my answer to this flow.
Let's start with:

- avoiding the !! non null operator in the response.body()!!.
  If you mark that the response body is not null, in case it is it will crash,  local.deleteTask should receive a body response nullable parameter and should handle the possible null body.

First the first; let's wrap the complete function in Repository into a try catch, something like:

```
try {
    val response = remote.deleteRemoteTask(token, id, task)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            local.deleteTask(response.body()!!)
            return local.getTaskByID(response.body()!!.id)
        } else {
           throw Exception("Repo: API Call unsuccessful")
        }
} catch(e: Exception) {
  throw e
}
```

Let's check why that response is not successful, I see you throwing an Exception with a message in case the response is not successful, try to throw the Exception with the response.code(), something like:

```
try {
val response = remote.deleteRemoteTask(token, id, task)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            local.deleteTask(response.body()!!)
            return local.getTaskByID(response.body()!!.id)
        } else {
            throw Exception("Repo: API Call unsuccessful, response error code: ${response.code()}")
        }
} catch(e: Exception) {
  throw e
}
```

In your RepoImplementation, let's print that Exception stack trace and log it:

```
override suspend fun deleteRemoteTask(token: String, id: Int, task : Task): Response<Task> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return@withContext try {
             apiService.deleteTask(token, id, task)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "deleteRemoteTask: Api Failed to run, stack trace: ${e.printStackTrace()}")
        }
    }
```

Then in the logcat you can search for the TAG and see what is going on with that response. Let me know how it goes :D